# custom UIFont issue in XCode

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I am working with custom fonts and I have applied a custom font called "**CicleSemi**", I have added this font in **info.plist** file and below is the code which I have written

```
 DateLabel.font   = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CicleSemi" size:15.0];
```

This works fine, for **english language in my app,** but for **russian language** , I know that this font is not available , **so Xcode automatically shifts to system font** and its shifting also but the issue is that the font is becoming "BOLD" but I want it normal, and I dont have any clue what might be the issue, how xcode is treating this.

So friends, if you have any clue or suggestions please let me know.

Regards
Ranjit